# Make the background of the current active sidebar element transparent

Tags: html, css, background, sidebar, transparent

I recently created this sidebar, however I do not know how I am supposed to make the white background (only of the currently active element) transparent so that if the main content has a background image it will show behind the sidebar (otherwise it will look like the second picture, which is not what I'm trying to achieve).

The way this sidebar works is that if an item is 'active' it's given a white background color (over the dark sidebar one), its left borders are rounded, and then its ::after and ::before elements are absolutely positioned and given a rounded box-shadow (also white) which gives the look of the rounded right corners.

[The sidebar with a white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEYim.png)

[The sidebar with an image as a background (not what I was looking for)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQI2u.png)

[An example of how it should look like, using mix-blend-mode (This is still not what I'm looking for too many things have a semi-transparent background)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gp3l.jpg)

I've already created a semi-working version with mix-blend-mode, however that is not doing everything I'd like it to (it also changes the colors for the other elements, the ones that aren't active).
I've also tried to experiment with the mask and clip properties and am pretty sure a more reliable solution would require one of them, however I am not sure how I would go about it.

If anyone knows how to I'd appreciate it if you would let me know. Thanks in advance!

Code (svelte):

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { Ripple } from '$lib/ripple/Ripple';
    import { isThemeDark } from '$lib/theme';
    import { Tooltip } from '$lib/tooltip/Tooltip';

    // The props for the background and foreground colors
    export let backgroundColorLight: string = 'rgb(30 41 59)';
    export let foreColorLight: string = 'white';
    export let backgroundColorDark: string = 'rgb(241, 245, 241)';
    export let foreColorDark: string = 'rgb(30 41 59)';

    let sidebar: HTMLElement;

    // Depending on the theme sets the color
    onMount(() => {
        if ($isThemeDark) {
            sidebar.style.setProperty('--forecolor', foreColorDark);
            sidebar.style.setProperty('--background-color', backgroundColorDark);
        } else {
            sidebar.style.setProperty('--forecolor', foreColorLight);
            sidebar.style.setProperty('--background-color', backgroundColorLight);
        }
    });

    // The Material Design Icons
    import { mdiCog, mdiExitToApp, mdiHomeOutline, mdiMenu, mdiViewDashboard } from '@mdi/js';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    import MdiIcon from './MdiIcon.svelte';

    let open = false;

    // The sidebar items (apart from the burger menu and the logout button)
    let sidebarItems: {
        label: string;
        iconPath: string;
        path: string;
    }[] = [
        {
            label: 'Home',
            iconPath: mdiHomeOutline,
            path: '/'
        },
        {
            label: 'Dashboard',
            iconPath: mdiViewDashboard,
            path: '/dashboard'
        },
        {
            label: 'Settings',
            iconPath: mdiCog,
            path: '/account/settings'
        }
    ];
</script>

<!--The sidebar code-->
<!--use:Ripple and use:Tooltip don't matter for this question so I haven't included the code.-->
<aside class="sidebar" class:open bind:this={sidebar}>
    <button class="sidebar-item">
        <span
            class="sidebar-icon"
            on:mousedown={() => {
                open = !open;
            }}
            use:Ripple={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}><MdiIcon path={mdiMenu} /></span
        >
    </button>
    <!--Loops through the sidebar items and places an <a> for each one-->
    {#each sidebarItems as item}
        <a class="sidebar-item" class:active={window.location.pathname == item.path} href={item.path}>
            <span
                class="sidebar-icon"
                use:Tooltip={{
                    tippy: { content: item.label, arrow: false, placement: 'right' },
                    canShow: !open
                }}
                use:Ripple={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}><MdiIcon path={item.iconPath} /></span
            >
            <p class="sidebar-text">{item.label}</p>
        </a>
    {/each}

    <div class="sidebar-item">
        <span
            class="sidebar-icon"
            use:Tooltip={{
                tippy: { content: 'Log out', arrow: false, placement: 'right' },
                canShow: !open
            }}
            use:Ripple={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}><MdiIcon path={mdiExitToApp} /></span
        >
        <p class="sidebar-text">Log out</p>
    </div>
</aside>

<style lang="scss">
    .sidebar {
        padding: 0;
        color: var(--forecolor);
        background-color: var(--background-color);
        margin: 0;
        width: 5rem;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        transition: 0.2s ease;
    }

    .sidebar.open {
        width: 16rem;
    }

    .sidebar-item {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        align-items: center;
        height: 5rem;
        // This is what makes the left border rounded
        border-top-left-radius: 16px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
    }

    .sidebar-item:nth-last-child(1) {
        margin-top: auto;
    }

    .sidebar-item.active {
        margin-left: 0.2rem;
        color: var(--background-color);
        background-color: var(--forecolor);
        // The ::before and ::after are absolutely positioned and a box shadow is given to them to make the right white rounded border for active elements
        &::before,
        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        &::before {
            top: -30px;
            clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
            box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 var(--forecolor);
        }
        &::after {
            bottom: -30px;
            box-shadow: 15px -15px 0 var(--forecolor);
            clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
        }
    }

    // Secondary code, just to prevent the sidebar icons from looking crazy, and to make it so if the sidebar is closed the text won't show
    .sidebar-icon {
        width: 3.2rem;
        height: 3.2rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 0.6rem;
        margin: -0.6rem 0.9rem;
    }
    .sidebar-text {
        display: none;
    }
    .sidebar.open .sidebar-text {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

I've already looked at other stackoverflow questions, however none of them discussed only having part of the background be transparent, not the entire background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather involved solution that may still need some adaption for your purposes, but it hopefully conforms to your needs. Essentially, you need the background of the active element to be transparent. Which wouldn't be an issue if not for the rounded cut-outs.

My solution involves a set of pseudo-elements to overlay the hidden parts. One for top, one for bottom, and another within a wrapper for the left side. The element itself becomes rather large due to that though.

Edit: I have trouble making the preview here work properly, so here is my [pen](https://codepen.io/Tetrakern/pen/ZEJZgJd). (Edit 2: Works now.)

```css
/* Just some setup for the example */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/jzfvkR8/wp5961294-aesthetic-minecraft-pc-wallpapers.png');
  height: 300px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 64px;
}

.sidebar::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Relevant stuff */
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Rounded corners top/bottom */
.item::before,
.item::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: white;
  height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Bottom-right rounded corner for top pseudo-element */
.item.active::before {
  border-radius: 0 0 16px 0;
}

/* Top-right rounded corner for bottom pseudo-element */
.item.active::after {
  border-radius: 0 16px 0 0;
}

/* Account for top/bottom pseudo-element space */
.item > div {
  padding: 16px 0;
}

/* Let background image show through */
.item.active {
  background: none;
}

/* Rounded inset corners on the left side */
.item.active > div::before {
  /* Make sure to not block the interactive menu item */
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px; 
  left: 1px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 16px 0 0 16px;
  /* Account for top/bottom pseudo-elements */
  height: calc(100% - 32px);
  width: 16px;
  box-shadow: -16px 0 0 16px #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="item">
      <div>FOO</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <div>BAR</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div>BAZ</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tetrakern's answer I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. After some tinkering I got to a solution which achieved everything I needed, while also avoiding having a very big padding for the elements themselves.
The changes I made to my original design:

1. Used .sidebar::after to make the bottom middle of the sidebar have a background color of white.
2. Removed the color: and background-color: properties from .sidebar
3. Removed the old code for rendering the rounded borders
4. Used JavaScript to select the previous and next children (I could've used css for the next child however the previous one would use :has which is experimental, so I chose to stick with JS for both), and then gave the border radius to those.
5. Used .sidebar-item.active::before to create the left rounded borders feel I was going for.

**[The codepen](https://codepen.io/DeltaRays/pen/yLoWrKZ)**

It's not perfect (because I just made it to showcase how the new code looks like), but it works ;-)

HTML:

```html
<!-- Inter Font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" />
<!--Code-->
<div class="page">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <p class="sidebar-text">Home</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-item active">
      <p class="sidebar-text">View</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <p class="sidebar-text">Quit</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-item">
      <p class="sidebar-text">Extra</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page {
  font-family: "Inter";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 23, 238, 0.63),
      rgba(48, 0, 239, 0.4)
    ),
    url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/533643380790394881/912783535067254824/index-background-light.jpg");
}

.sidebar {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-menu {
    text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}
.sidebar-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0rem;
}

.sidebar-item.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-item.active::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 16px 0 0 16px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16px;
  box-shadow: -16px 0 0 16px #fff;
}
```

JS:

```js
let activeGuy = document.querySelector(".sidebar-item.active");
let sidebarItems = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar > *");
for (let i = 0; i < sidebarItems.length; i++) {
  sidebarItems[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", (ev) => {
    activeGuy.classList.remove("active");
    activeGuy = ev.target;
    activeGuy.classList.add("active");
    calculateBorderRadius();
  });
}
calculateBorderRadius();
function calculateBorderRadius() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sidebarItems.length; i++) {
    sidebarItems[i].style.borderRadius = "0";
  }
  let prev = activeGuy.previousElementSibling;
  let next = activeGuy.nextElementSibling;
  prev.style.borderBottomRightRadius = "20px";
  next.style.borderTopRightRadius = "20px";
}
```